# How do i maintain 'topic branch' history of a merge in git?

Tags: git

I am currently creating topic branches:

```
git checkout -b topic_branch
...do work...
git checkout master
git merge topic_branch
```

but currently when I do this, I lose history of my 'topic_branch' and all of the commits just show up.

How do i get the topic branch merge history to show up on my merge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `--no-ff` switch to your `git merge` line and you will always create a merge commit, even if the merge could have otherwise been resolved as a fast-forward.

Answer (score 0):

The history of the merged branch is present in the result, just not as the "principal" (first) parent. Run e.g. `gitk` on the result, and you will see it all.